# Websockets in Jelastic: DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, jelastic

I'm trying to play with websockets, so I created WS server like that:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat")
public class WsChatServlet{
private static final Logger LOGGER =
        Logger.getLogger(WsChatServlet.class.getName());

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "New connection with client: {0}",
            session.getId());
}

@OnMessage
public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "New message from Client [{0}]: {1}",
            new Object[] {session.getId(), message});
    return "Server received [" + message + "]";
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Close connection for client: {0}",
            session.getId());
}

@OnError
public void onError(Throwable exception, Session session) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Error for client: {0}", session.getId());
}
}
```

and deployed it in Tomcat 7 running on Java 7.
Then I created that client:

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class Main {
private static final String uri = "ws://myserver.net/chat";

public static void main(String[] args) throws DeploymentException, IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
    WebSocketContainer wsContainer =  ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    Session session = wsContainer.connectToServer(Main.class, new URI(uri));
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Here is a message!");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    session.close();
}

@OnMessage public void processMessage(String message){
    System.out.println(message);
}
}
```

This client runs as a comand-line app. When I run it, I get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [HTTP/1.1 302 Found] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket
```

So it looks like server doesn't responds propertly to my client. I noticed that if I access `ws://myserver.net/chat`, than it responds with 302, but for `ws://myserver.net/chat/` (notice `/`) it responds with 200 OK.

More interesting is this Tomcat logs:

- - [01/Oct/2014:15:52:35 +0000] "GET /chat/ HTTP/1.0" 200 57
- - [01/Oct/2014:15:52:42 +0000] "GET /chat HTTP/1.0" 302 -

As you may see my client connects with HTTP 1.0, not 1.1, which may be wrong.
I am completely stucked with it. Don't understand why it doesn't work.

**EDIT:**
So, my main question is why websockets doesn't work (I guess HTTP Upgrade response header missed) and how to fix that.

**EDIT2:**
I forgot most important thing: I deploy it in free Jelastic environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally I found what went wrong and the answer is: Jelastic.
I deployed my app to the free Jelastic instance, that means all requests were proxyed by nginx. As mentioned [here](http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/10/29/shared-resolver-and-public-ip-in-jelastic/), you must obtain public IP to let your app work with WebSockets in Jelastic.

Comment: So if i dont have public IP in Jelastic i can't get my websocket working?

Comment: @KuKeC that's right: you can't get websocket working without public IP

Answer (score 0):

as stated by wikipedia:

> The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing URL redirection

and that 200 OK is the

> Standard response for successful HTTP requests

So based on you situation, I guess you explorer is saving the first request with a trailing slash, in either case, the http status is Found or OK, the resource is found.

finally I guess changing the value of *sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash* to false would solve the problem and the response will be always 200 OK. (for changing it check [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html))

if this didn't work, many reasons can push tomcat to add trailing slash, check [this discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/567203/Tomcat/control-redirection-http-https-trailing) for other reasons

Comment: OK, thanks for hint with _sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash_ but my main question was why websockets don't work (HTTP Upgrade response header missed?) and how may I fix that.

Comment: provide us the whole webSocket traffic so that we can understand what's happening, use fiddler if you want.